# Quill Editor - get total number of lines / dynamically set editor height

Tags: javascript, quill

I need to get a number of lines of text entered into editor by user, because initial height of the editor is small, but after user enters some text and it wraps into a new line, I need to increase the height of the editor.

I managed to get the number only if user presses enter, because then Quill adds a new `<p>` tag. Otherwise, if he just types text and it breaks into a new line, I can't find a way to get the total number of text lines. Here is an example:

```
var quill = new Quill('#editor-container', {
  theme: 'snow'
});

quill.root.style['max-height'] = '81px';
quill.root.style['border-bottom'] = '1px solid grey';

trackHeight = () => { 
  let length = quill.getLength();
  let lines = quill.getLines(0, length);
    if (lines.length < 2) {
      quill.root.style['min-height'] = '101px';
    }
    if (lines.length > 2) {
      quill.root.style['min-height'] = '120px';
    }
    if (lines.length > 3) {
      quill.root.style['min-height'] = '140px';
    }        
    if (lines.length > 4) {
      quill.root.style['min-height'] = '160px';
    }                      
};   

quill.on('text-change', this.trackHeight);
```

You can just copy/paste code above into a [quill playground](https://quilljs.com/playground/).

Note that if you press enter, size increases, but if you just type until text wraps into a separate line, editor height remains the same, because `lines.length` property doesn't increase.

Any advice here?

Comment: What you want doesnt make sense! A new line is added whenever user presses enter because that will add a P tag to the string. The number of lines you see is dependent on your screen size, I can have a 40 inch screen and still be on line one whereas the same string on a 16 inch monitor can be 4+ lines.

Comment: @Siyavash - you just described the problem. I asked for a solution

Answer (score 1):

Solution:

```
var quill = new Quill('#editor-container', {
  theme: 'snow'
});

quill.root.style['max-height'] = '81px';
quill.root.style['border-bottom'] = '1px solid grey';

trackHeight = () => { 
  let length = quill.getLength();
  let scrollHeight = quill.root.scrollHeight;
    quill.root.style['min-height'] = Math.min(scrollHeight, 500) + 'px';
    if(length < 50) {
      quill.root.style['min-height'] = '41px';
    }                
};   

quill.root.style['min-height'] = '41px';

quill.on('text-change', this.trackHeight);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do:

```
const numberOfLines = this.quill.getLines().length;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just set `overflow` to `visible` and it will handle automatically.

```
.ql-editor {
  overflow-y: visible !important;
}
```